# What's wrong with Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

could please somebody tell me, what is wrong with Gulp?

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./scss/**/*', ['scss']);
    gulp.src('/')
        .pipe(webserver({
            fallback: 'index.html',
            livereload: true,
            directoryListing: {
                enable: true,
                path: '/'
            },
            open: false,
        }));
});
```

When running gulp watch, get

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/tmp/KSOutOfProcessFetcher.0.ppfIhqX0vjaTSb8AJYobDV7Cu68='
at Error (native)
```

What's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you dont have permissions to scan the folder youre specifying.

Try the following

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./scss/**/*', ['scss']);
  gulp.src('./')
      .pipe(webserver({
          fallback: 'index.html',
          livereload: true,
          directoryListing: {
            enable: true,
            path: './'
        },
        open: false,
    }));
});
```

The root `/` of the file system is replaced with `./`, the relative current folder.